# How to filter SharePointList in order only the next (smallest) not yet completed working step is displayed in gallery

Tags: powerapps

I have a large SharePointList. The SharePoint list looks as follows:

| PurchaseOrder | WorkingStep | Technology | Completed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **1** | **milling** | **false** |
| 1 | 2 | milling | false |
| 2 | 1 | milling | true |
| **2** | **2** | **drilling** | **false** |
| 3 | 1 | drilling | true |
| **3** | **2** | **cutting** | **false** |
| **3** | **2** | **milling** | **false** |
| 3 | 3 | drilling | false |
| 999 | 1 | drilling | true |
| 999 | 2 | milling | true |

The SharePointList consists of several purchase orders which contain multiple working steps.
Most of the purchase orders are already finished (Completed = true). This already reduces the sharepoint list drastically.

How can I filter a gallery (Property: Items) in order to see only the WorkingSteps that have not yet been completed ( Filter(SharePointList, Completed = false) ) **AND** which are the smallest WorkingStep within their PurchaseOrder that have not yet been completed?

For example working step 3 of purchase order 3 is at the present not relevant for me because there are two working steps before which have to be done. Working step 1 of purchase order 3 is already completed.

This should result in a gallery that only contains the entries in **bold** (see table above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GroupBy` and then only show the first item. Try something similar to:

```
With({
  spListIncomplete: SortByColumns(
    Filter(SharePointList, Completed = false), 
    "PurchaseOrder", SortOrder.Ascending, "WorkingStep", SortOrder.Ascending
  )},
  GroupBy(spListIncomplete, "PurchaseOrder", "Steps")
)
```

Then in your gallery, only show the first item in the group. For example:

```
First(ThisItem.Steps).WorkingStep
```

```
First(ThisItem.Steps).Technology
```

`PurchaseOrder` won't be in the grouped items, so:

```
ThisItem.PurchaseOrder
```